# I Need to write a program which converts number 0-999 to words

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert a number from 0-999 to words.

Example: 504 = five hundred and four.

Currently I'm stuck on converting 3 digit numbers

```
    //converting from 101 to 999
    if(number >= 100 && number < 1000) {
        result = number / 100; //getting hundreds
        //getting tens, and finding tens, and teens numbers
        tmpTen = number % 100;
        if(tmpTen > 0 && tmpTen < 20)//if teen go get it
        {
            tmpTeen = tmpTen % 10;
            teen = true; 
        } else //if not a teen split number
            tmpTen /= 10;
        //finding digits
        tmpDigit = number % 10;
        if(!teen)//if final result doesn't include teen numbers print the following
            System.out.println(digits[result]+" "+hundred+" and "+tens[tmpTen-1]+" "+digits[tmpDigit]);
        else
            System.out.println(digits[result]+" "+hundred+" and "+teens[tmpTeen-1]); 
    }
    System.out.print("Number: ");
    number = In.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: "five hundred and four" vs "five hundred four" is a matter of preference, no?

Comment: "five hundred and four" = 500.4, "Five hundred four" is the correct grammar

Comment: Instead of `" " + hundred + " and "` try `" hundred and "`.

Comment: I added the necessary declarations and initializations, and now your program prints `five hundred and four` on my computer. So what do you mean by stuck? Tell us your expected and actual output and any error messages.

Comment: ok sweet thanks alot. I just need to write my program so that when i type in 504 it doesn't print "five hundred and"